# drop down listbox always select the first value

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I am using c# asp.net and c# where i try to filter an amchart using a dropdown listbox. But no matter what i select i get the value f the first element, I tried !ispostback, but no luck,
The following is the frontend code,

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default"  EnableEventValidation = "false" %>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

    <head>


        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>amCharts examples</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/style1.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://localhost/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var chart;

            var chartData = JSON.parse('<%=sjson%>'); 

            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.categoryField = "Ip";
                chart.startDuration = 1;

                //scrollbar definition
                var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();

                // AXES
                // category
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
                categoryAxis.gridPosition = "Count";

                // value
                // in case you don't want to change default settings of value axis,
                // you don't need to create it, as one value axis is created automatically.

                // GRAPH
                var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.valueField = "Count";
                graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
                graph.type = "column";
                graph.lineAlpha = 0;
                graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;

                //add scrollbar to graph
                chartScrollbar.graph = graph;
                chartScrollbar.scrollbarHeight = 40;
                chartScrollbar.color = "#000000";
                chartScrollbar.autoGridCount = true;
                chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

                chart.addGraph(graph);

                chart.write("chartdiv");
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListISP" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListISP_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

And following is my code behind,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string sjson;
    string connStr = "server=localhost;Database=db_tav;Uid=root;Pwd=pass;";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) { 
            populateList();
            filterData("etisalat");
        }

    }
    private void populateList() {
        MySqlConnection connPopulate = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

        connPopulate.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        cmd = connPopulate.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT isp FROM tbl_correlateTest WHERE isp !=''";//

        MySqlDataReader ddlValues;
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DropDownListISP.DataSource = ddlValues;
        DropDownListISP.DataValueField = "isp";
        DropDownListISP.DataTextField = "isp";
        DropDownListISP.DataBind();

        connPopulate.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }
    private void filterData(string isp) {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IP, conLvl FROM tbl_correlateTest WHERE isp LIKE ?ispVal order by ip asc";//
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?ispVal", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "%" + isp + "%";
        MySqlDataReader readIp = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        ArrayList conRc = new ArrayList();

        while (readIp.Read())
        {
            string ipVal = readIp.GetString(0);
            string conLvlVal = readIp.GetString(1);
            conRc.Add(new Confidence(ipVal, conLvlVal));

        }

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        sjson = oSerializer.Serialize(conRc);

        conn.Close();        
    }
    protected void DropDownListISP_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string isp = DropDownListISP.SelectedValue.ToString();
        isp = isp.Trim();
        filterData(isp);
    }

}
```

PLEASE help me on this one, i tried everything i can but this listbox always returns the first value :( thank you very much.. :)

---

EDIT:

I can retrieve the selected item value if i perform the following instead of data bind.

```
    MySqlDataReader readIsp = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    while (readIsp.Read())
    {
        string ispVal = readIsp.GetString(0);
        ispVal = ispVal.Trim();
        DropDownListISP.Items.Add(ispVal);

    }
```

any idea what the issue is?? just for information.. :)

Comment: Hasitha, I don't know if i got what you want exactly but, Where do you set the selected value of the `DropDownList`, it suppose to set like `DropDownListISP.SelectedValue` , if you didn't set it will always be on the first element by default.

Comment: try once `if(!Page.IsPostBack){}`

Comment: @MohamedFarrag i set it in the last function 'DropDownListISP_SelectedIndexChanged' it returns the same thing :(

Comment: @satindersingh I tried it but it didn't solve the problem..as you can see i have used that condion on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If binding the data is raising the issue and adding the items is not, than it means that `populateList` is being called, and when dropdown is binded again, previous selection is washed out. Put a break point in the `populateList` method and see if it gets hit when you do a post back from dropdown.

Comment: try to do one more thing, remove the entire javascript from the page and simply do the posting back from dropdown list and see if the values are coming, as sometimes problem in javascript also creates such issue.